# Changing UPN via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working on changing all users' UPNs via Powershell. I run the following script without error. However, none of the UPNs change. When I run a partial script to get the properties, I see extra info on the properties.

Script to change the UPN:

```bsh
$ou = "DC=companyname,DC=office"
$local = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -filter * -Properties userPrincipalName -ResultSetSize $null
$local | foreach { 
  $newUpn = $_.UserPrincipalName.Replace("companyname.office", "companyname.com")
  $_ | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $newUpn 
}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At Y:\it\powershell scripts\upn_change.ps1:11 char:19
+ ...  | ForEach {$newUpn = $_.UserPrincipalName.Replace("companyname.office"," ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Set-ADUser : The operation failed because UPN value provided for addition/modification is not unique forest-wide
At Y:\it\powershell scripts\upn_change.ps1:11 char:96
+ ... e.office","companyname.com"); $_ | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $newUpn}
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=ComanyName,DC=office:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8648,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

I know that changing a user from **.office** to **.com** works as I have a small test group that I have been working with that I changed manually.

**Update:**

Updated script to replace `$_.UserPrincipalName.Replace` with `$local[0].UserPrincipalName.Replace` along with using a test OU instead of the complete AD. I only get the second error now.

> Set-ADUser : The operation failed because UPN value provided for
>   addition/modification is not unique forest-wide At Y:\it\powershell
>   scripts\upn_change.ps1:11 char:103
>   + ... e.office","companyname.com"); $_ | Set-ADUser -UserPrincipalName $newUpn}
>   +                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Daniel McInt...riese,DC=office:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8648,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Welp -- not sure what I did.

I found another script online.

```
$upn = Get-Aduser......  (essentially the same as $local above). The rest is what I think did it - foreach { Set-ADUser $_ -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@{1}" -f $_.name,"kfriese.com")}
```

So the whole script is like this:

```
$upn | foreach { Set-ADUser $_ -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@{1}" -f $_.name,"kfriese.com")}
```

And now, all is good. I used my test OU and all the UPNs changed to .com. May not be the exact way that is recommended to do this, but it worked.

Comment: The new error implies that `$_.UserPrinciplName` is `$null`. The 2nd error is presumably just a follow-on effect of the 1st error.

Comment: Try `$local[0].UserPrincipalName.Replace("companyname.office","companyname.com")` just to be sure nothing is null and the replace is working.

Comment: Based off the error message, you are trying to set two users to the same UPN. Are you sure that the UPN you are setting for that user is unique in your Forest? i.e. in Active Directory Users and Computers, can you manually set that user to the new UPN?

Comment: HAL9256 - currently I have it set to only a single OU with 7 unique users to that OU. Yes, I can manually set each one from .office to .com